# "More than one remote source not supported" when copying files via pscp

Tags: linux, windows

I need to copy a file from Windows to Ubuntu 12.04. I have tried using the code below:

```
pscp C:\abc.php username@server: .
```

But it shows an error:

> `More than one remote source not supported`

How to solve this?

Comment: Wrap your arguments in double quotes.
`pscp "C:\abc.php" "username@server:/path/to/abc.php"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you specify more than one remote source. `username@server: .` ← the dot here (which supposedly means your working directory) doesn't belong there. You cannot reference your working directory on another machine like this, and since there's a space between `username@server` and `.`, it'll be interpreted as two arguments.

Instead, specify an absolute path:

```
pscp C:\abc.php username@server:/home/user/foo
```

Comment: hello slhck. Thanks for your reply. I have used your code and it is displaying me error like: C:abc.php: No such file or directory. The file is there on the same location but somehow pscp command is unable to find it. and it displays C:abc.php not C:\abc.php what to do?

Comment: Is that the real path you're using or just an example? Normally it should work – maybe you can give us the actual command you're using.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Windows path, chances are that you may have folders/directories with spaces in them, and these can cause that error as well. You may resolve this by using double quotes around your path. That was my problem

```
pscp -<arguments> username@server:/home/folder/file "C:\your windows path"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the "more than one remote source not supported" error, and it turned out it was because I was giving a file name in the destination.

I'm running on a Windows 7 box, trying to bring down a file from a Linux box. I tried:

```
pscp -l myusername IPADDRESS:/home/myfolder/myfilename.txt C:\Users\myuserfolder\myfilename.txt
```

**No good**.

Once I removed the filename in the target, it worked fine.  **This worked**:

```
pscp -l myusername IPADDRESS:/home/myfolder/myfilename.txt C:\Users\myuserfolder
```

Answer (score 0):

Carefully consider The **space** before the dot (.) in your above input *"pscp C:\abc.php username@server: . "* is considering as two arguments considering as two sources, It is deemed as an info and displays no more than 1 source is not supported.

Also Try follow this [How to transfer files between linux and windows using putty](http://www.nairabytes.net/blog/62-geek/297-how-to-transfer-files-between-linux-and-windows-using-putty)

Answer (score 0):

seems like filename in local destination not affecting. It can be present or empty.

This line worked for me (copying sql dump from remote to local):

```
pscp -pw ssh_pass -P 29477 ssh_user@ssh_host:/tmp/cafe.sql d:\temp\cafe.sql
```

Answer (score -1):

this works for me on windows 7
command transfers test.wav from the windows folder your in to the pi's web directory
pscp test.wav pi@xxx.xxx.x.xx:/var/www/html/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).